# Reduce a page size then add it to Page Viewer Web Part SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, web-part, page-layout

I created a page ASPX in mysite, I have an image map on this page, which has lots of **areas**. When users mouse over these areas, the relatived information will displays.

I want to add this page to my home page with a Page Viewer Web Part. But the image map is too large. If I edit width/height of Page Viewer Web Part, it just displays partial image map. How can I reduce this page size like zoom out, then add it to  Page Viewer Web Part?

I cannot modify width/height of image on my page ASPX, because I use coords to add lots of areas. If I change the size of image, I should modify all areas.....
The best way I think is zoom out the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I change my way. I add a web part editor content, then add these code to reduce my image map, not very perfect but it works......

```
.map{
-webkit-transform:translate(-100px,-450px) scale(0.6);   /* Safari */
-ms-transform:translate(-100px,-450px) scale(0.6);   /* IE 9 */
transform:translate(-100px,-450px) scale(0.6);
}
```